# Failed to resolve: com

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, resolve

I tried to build my android project ( react-native ) and it gives me this error
`Failed to resolve: com`

And when i click on open the file, it show a line in app build.gradle

`apply plugin: "com.android.application"`

This is my app gradle file

```
      buildscript {
          repositories {
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
          }

          dependencies {
            classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
          }
        }
        apply plugin: "com.android.application"
        apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
        //apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

        repositories {
          maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        }

        android {
          compileSdkVersion 27
          buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

          flavorDimensions "default"

          defaultConfig {
            applicationId "[APPLICATINO ID]"
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 8
            versionName '1.0.5'
            ndk {
              abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
            }
            multiDexEnabled true
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            // Deprecated. Used by net.openid:appauth
            manifestPlaceholders = [
              'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'host.exp.exponent'
            ]
          }
          dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize System.getenv("DISABLE_DEX_MAX_HEAP") ? null : "8g"
          }
          productFlavors {
            // Define separate dev and prod product flavors.
            dev {
              // dev utilizes minSDKVersion = 21 to allow the Android gradle plugin
              // to pre-dex each module and produce an APK that can be tested on
              // Android Lollipop without time consuming dex merging processes.
              minSdkVersion 21
            }
            devRemoteKernel {
              minSdkVersion 21
            }
            dev19 {
              // For debugging / development on older SDK versions. Increases build
              // time so use 'dev' if not running on older SDKs.
              minSdkVersion 19
            }
            prod {
              // The actual minSdkVersion for the application.
              minSdkVersion 19
            }
          }
          buildTypes {
            debug {
              debuggable true
            }
            release {
              minifyEnabled true
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
              zipAlignEnabled true
            }
          }
          signingConfigs {
            debug {
              storeFile file('../debug.keystore')
            }
          }
          lintOptions {
            abortOnError false
          }
          packagingOptions {
            pickFirst "**"
          }
        }

        // Don't use modern jsc-android since it still has some critical bugs that
        // crash applications when the string for the JS bundle is loaded and when
        // locale-specific date functions are called.
        // configurations.all {
        //   resolutionStrategy {
        //     force 'org.webkit:android-jsc:r216113'
        //   }
        // }


        apply from: 'expo.gradle'


        dependencies {
          // This should be here already
          implementation project(':react-native-firebase')

          // Firebase dependencies
          implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
          implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"

          implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

          implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

          // Our dependencies
          implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

          // Our dependencies from ExpoView
          // DON'T ADD ANYTHING HERE THAT ISN'T IN EXPOVIEW. ONLY COPY THINGS FROM EXPOVIEW TO HERE.
          implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
          implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
          implementation('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.22.1') {
            exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
          }
        compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:3.1.1'
          implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
          implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
          implementation 'com.amplitude:android-sdk:2.9.2' // Be careful when upgrading! Upgrading might break experience scoping. Check with Jesse. See Analytics.resetAmplitudeDatabaseHelper
          implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
          implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:12.0.1'
          implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
          implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.1'
          implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
          implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
          implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.1'
          annotationProcessor 'com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Compiler:2.2.1'
          implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow-Core:2.2.1"
          implementation "com.raizlabs.android:DBFlow:2.2.1"
          implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.53.0.0"
          implementation "com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.53.0.0"
          debugImplementation 'com.s quareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
          // debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta1'
          releaseImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta1'
          implementation 'com.facebook.device.yearclass:yearclass:1.0.1'
          implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:1.3.2'
          implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.4@aar'
          implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
          implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
          implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.1'
          implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.10'
          implementation 'com.segment.analytics.android:analytics:4.3.0'
          implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
          implementation 'net.openid:appauth:0.4.1'
          implementation('com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.5')  {
              exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'appcompat-v7'
          }
          implementation 'io.branch.sdk.android:library:2.17.1'
          implementation('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
            transitive = false
          }
          implementation 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.1.1'
          implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
          implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
          implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-ws:3.4.1'
          implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.9.0'

          // Testing
        //  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
          // We use a modified build of com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1. Explanation in maven-test/README
          androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
          androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
          androidTestImplementation 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.0'
          androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.1'
          androidTestImplementation 'com.azimolabs.conditionwatcher:conditionwatcher:0.2'

          testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
          testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
          testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.8'


          implementation('host.exp.exponent:expoview:28.0.0@aar') {
            transitive = true
          }


        }

        // This has to be down here for some reason
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And here is my logcat result: https://justpaste.it/60b4o

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `http proxy` in setting. the fabric library is restricted in some countries like Iran

Comment: Thanks .. i tried it and still get the same error
But this time when i open the file it points to this line ` implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'` not the one mentioned in the question

Comment: please add the build.gradle file exactly as it is. and add your logcat trace too.

Comment: I updated with the complete build.gradle ( app level) but i don't know how to add logcat as its infinite list of messages even when filtering for appliction .. Sorry Im not expert android developer

Comment: try upgrading multidex version to 1.0.3 and read this https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex

Comment: I did it , but still same error unfortunately :(  on the same line

Comment: regarding your main answer: auto-detect proxy setting would be enough for fix it when Im running vpn on my computer ( not just browser )?

Comment: I have to see your logcat otherwise i cannot help more

Comment: you can set manual proxy to be sure that ip and host are correctly set. use ultrasurf as vpn

Comment: no I just want the part which alerts the error not the whole logcat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176487/discussion-between-fakhruddin-abdi-and-masoud-vali).